# How can I fill non-exist value with 0 when use wm_concat in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table partitioned by pt.
Data:

> k   v    pt
>
> 100  1    20150101
>
> 101  1    20150102
>
> 100  1    20150103

I want to use wm_concat to get result like this, where non-existed k in partition filled with 0:

> k    ts
>
> 100  1,0,1
>
> 101  0,1,0

But I can only get result like this:

> k    ts
>
> 100  1,1
>
> 101  1

Hive script is as bellow:

---

```
select m1.k, wm_concat(',', m1.v) as ts
from
(
    select k, v, pt
    from test_table
    where pt <= ${date}
    order by pt
) m1
group by m1.k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to first do a cross-join with a subquery of distinct partitions and calculate a new "v" column which has a value of 1 when the pt exists for a particular k and a value of 0 otherwise. Then you need to take the max for each k, v pair grouping by pt. Here is what I mean:

```
select k, max(if(pt_join.pt == tb.pt, 1, 0)) as v, pt_join.pt as pt
from test_table tb
cross join (select distinct pt
            from test_table) pt_join
group by k, pt_join.pt
```

This will output the following:

```
k       v       pt
100     1       20150101
100     0       20150102
100     1       20150103
101     0       20150101
101     1       20150102
101     0       20150103
```

Then you should be able to use your method above to obtain the result you want:

```
k ts

100 1,0,1

101 0,1,0
```